# Where is a mysql database hostname configured?

Tags: linux

From the following, where in a LEMP stack does one configure the mysql hostname for 'database01' ;

```
            // Database credentials
            define( 'DB_NAME',     'my-database'      );
            define( 'DB_USER',     'my-username'     );
            define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'verylongpassword' );
            define( 'DB_HOST',     'database01'       );
```

is it;
 etc/mysql/my.conf

or is it
 etc/hostname

and is it possible to configure that hostname to connect to a different IP address?  (ie WAN IP).

Comment: Mysql does not configure the hostname, that is configured on operating system level. If the hostname in the code belongs to a different server, then that's where the code will try to connect to.

Comment: Yes, ok, so where in the OS is this non-localhost/additional hostname configured ?

Comment: There is no additional hostname configured for mysql anywhere.

Comment: @ericTbear generally the hostname is set in `/etc/hostname`. If you are attempting to connect to a host that is not the same as `localhost` (regardless of hostname), you will need to configure `mysql` to allow connections from that host (or subnet). That can be done on a per-database basis.

Comment: Its called database01,  where is the config file that defines it as database01  v's anyothernamewemightchoosetocallit

Comment: let me ask this another way

Answer (score 0):

Read this official [mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-server-management-wizard.html) they explained it in details.

If you already hosted project then you can go to Web Hosting > Select Databases.

then connect to the database using the IP address in the Database server column.

Like, Do not include the port following the IP address for your MySQL databases. For example, if your Database Server is 10.10.10.10:3306, use 10.10.10.10 as your database's hostname.

Answer (score 0):

answer is database01 is set in the etc/hosts file and has nothing to do with my.conf client or group settings.